# mysql remove 2 trailing dots starting at the end of string

Tags: mysql

How do i remove trailing dots starting from the end of the string.

I tried a bunch of stuff like TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM `column`)  and SUBSTRING but it doesn't fit the desired output due to my column value has a random length.

Here's my sample string:

```
 "www.facebook.com.102019.crt"
```

wanted to remove

```
".102019.crt"
```

in my string and it should look like this

```
"www.facebook.com"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the inputs were always of the form:

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.net
```

You could just use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.facebook.com.102019.crt', '.', 3);
```

This returns:

```
www.facebook.com
```

Comment: works perfectly, but how do i manage to delete the dots where not in exact index?

Comment: @user2597739 That's a good and completely valid question.  I didn't try to cover any edge cases because there are simply too many of them.  If you have some edge case data, maybe consider adding it to your question above.

Comment: @user2597739 Or ask a new question, If you update your question then Tim's answer may become invalid or in complete so its better to ask a new one.

Comment: thanks guys, but i managed to solved my last question by using substring_index in substr,
and it look like this 

select substr('www.facebook.test.com.102019.crt', 1, (length('www.facebook.test.com.102019.crt')- 
    length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(('www.facebook.test.com.102019.crt'), '.', -2))-1)) 
and im able to get "www.facebook.test.com"

Comment: @user2597739 A more robust solution might use regex.  If you are using MySQL 8+, then this would be an option.  Otherwise, you are pretty much limited to the sort of things as appear in my answer.